# Use Managed Identity with Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cosmosdb, azure-managed-identity, azure-cosmosdb-tables

I'd like to use managed identity when connecting to cosmos db table api from an azure function.

```
Uri tableEndpoint = new Uri("https://mycosmos.table.cosmos.azure.com:443/");
var tableServiceClient = new TableServiceClient(tableEndpoint, new DefaultAzureCredential());

var tableClient = tableServiceClient.GetTableClient(tableName);
```

This causes the following error:

> Authorization header doesn't confirm to the required format

I've read that cosmos db table api does not yet support managed identity but that was over 2 years ago - I'm hoping that it is now possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per November 2023, this is still not supported (see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-setup-rbac#which-azure-cosmos-db-apis-support-role-based-access-control)):

> ### Which Azure Cosmos DB APIs support role-based access control?
>
> The API for NoSQL is supported. Support for the API for MongoDB is in preview.

Azure Storage Table do support managed identity and could be an alternative:

- [Authorize access to tables using Microsoft Entra ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/authorize-access-azure-active-directory).
  you would need to grant `Storage Table Data Contributor` or `Storage Table Data Reader` role to the managed identity.

And here is a good article to check between storage and cosmos table:

- [Develop with Azure Cosmos DB for Table and Azure Table Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table/support?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Ftables%2Ftoc.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json)

Comment: Thanks Thomas but we’re actually in the process of moving from table storage to cosmos table api so we can benefit from multiple indexed columns. This gives us drastic performance improvements but I guess no managed identity option for time being.

Comment: Yeah you could always store the connectionstring in KV but would have been good to get it working